# WildFly 10 do deploy bug

Tags: web-applications, deployment, wildfly-8, wildfly-9, wildfly-10

I am using the latest version of WildFly, which is WildFly 10.0.0 final, and I am encountring a problem in deployment a folder which I am not facing when using WildFly 8.

My problem is that I have a web application folder and when I try to deploy it I get this error message:

> Deployment of '***.war' requested, but the deployment is not present.

I am sure that I am following the right instructions to deploy my application as it was deployed using WildFly 8 but not WildFly 9 and 10.

These are the instructions that I'm following to deploy my application:

1. Copy the web application folder to the standalone/deploymentsfolder,
2. rename my folder to XXX.war.dodeploy,
3. then go back to bin folder and run the standalone.bat file.

But I get either nothing or a message saying Deployment of '***.war' requested, but the deployment is not present.

Comment: What does the directory structure look like?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins it looks like this:
-/standalone

--/deployments
---/XXX.war.dodeploy
----home.xhtml
----/admin
-----index.xhtml
----images
----/META-INF
-----context.xml
----/pages
-----xhtml pages
-----/inc
----/resources
-----/font-awsome
-----/css
-----/jquery
-----/...etc

----/WEB-INF
-----web.xml
-----jboss-web.xml
-----faces-config.xml
-----/classes
-----/lib
-----/templates
-----/inc

Answer (score 3):

Actually, what you need to do is this:

1. Copy the web application folder to the `standalone/deployments` folder,
2. rename your folder to `XXX.war` **(without the `.dodeploy`part)**,
3. **create an empty file with the name `XXX.war.dodeploy` (this is actually what trigger the deployment of the web application named `XXX.war`)**
4. then go back to `bin` folder and run the `standalone.bat` file.

From https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Application+deployment:

> **Marker Files**
>
> The marker files always have the same name as the deployment content to which they relate, but with an additional file suffix appended. For example, the marker file to indicate the example.war file should be deployed is named example.war.dodeploy. Different marker file suffixes have different meanings.

Answer (score 0):

For deploying web applications in wildfly 10, you can either copy the war file directly to standalone/deployments folder or you could use the management console and choose the war file to deploy.

The deployment scanner scans the folder for any war files, and deploys them, and there is no necessity for any  .war.dodeploy file to be present, although creating such a file also gets it done.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the actual problem was that the name of the folder didn't match the name of dedeploy file.  If you're deploying an ear, or war, etc make sure the dodeploy files have the same exact name (except the dodeploy extension).  For example, assume we're deploying

- default_blah_1.0.ear           <--- This is your folder
- default_blah_1.0.ear.dodeploy  <-- this is your flag file (make sure the .ear is in there)